# I would like to know how the System.err works

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, outputstream

I am going through the Java IO. Just started with standard input and output streams. Please look at the simple program given below,

```
   public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give us your input");
        String str = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Standard Output: " + str);
        System.err.println("Standard Error Output: " +str );
    }
```

The output varies while running this two or three times. Please find couple of the outputs below,

Running for the first time:

Give us your input
my Name
Standard Error Output: my Name
Standard Output: my Name

Process finished with exit code 0

Running second time with the same code:
Give us your input
my Name
Standard Output: my Name
Standard Error Output: my Name

Process finished with exit code 0

I would like to know why the output changes with System.err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.out and System.err write to different streams that are connected via different pipes to your command shell.  The command shell will then read from these pipes and write the data to your console application.  That will ultimately write to your screen.

There are a number of places where data written to one stream could "overtake" data written to the other one.

- It could possibly occur in the JVM itself, since the Java specs make no guarantees about which stream gets written first.  (In fact, this is unlikely if there is only one thread doing the writing.  With current Java implementations, the behavior will probably be deterministic ... though unspecified.)
- It could be happening in the OS, since there are no guarantees on the order of delivery of data written to two independent pipes.
- It could be happening in the shell, since nothing in the shell specs place any priority of reading from the pipes.

In short, there are lots of areas where the behavior is unspecified.

It is also worth noting that the observed behavior is liable to depend on the version of Java you use, the OS and OS tools, your hardware, and the load on your system.

Finally, there is probably nothing that you could do to guarantee that the observed interleaving (or not) are consistent.  If you need consistency, write your output to one stream or the other exclusively.

Answer (score 3):

Your program will write to first `System.out` and then `System.err` (and `println` will flush these streams as well), but there is no guarantee in which order/interleaving the two streams will appear in your console.

Since you are writing to them at practically the same time, you will get both combinations. I suppose you might even get half-line interleavings.

Comment: I've ran this a number of times and no interleaving is taking place. Not sure why not though.

Comment: @mdewit: I don't think you will actually see interleaving unless you turn output stream flushing off or manually flush at weird places (and maybe not even then). But you *might*. At the end of the day, it is up to the console how/when to show this data.

Comment: You will see interleaving though if you write to a single stream (such as `System.out`) from multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: @mdewit I tried the same again by switching to another workspace in Eclipse and there is no interleaving with the streams. When I switched back I got the issue again.

Comment: It's not an issue. If  you don't explicitly synchronize/schedule, then the exact sequence is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

no guarantee of order for `System.out, System.in, System.err` anything can be appeared first so order of these streams are not fixed